# Mongodb lookup array of elements with combined result

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-lookup

So these are my two documents

Order document:

```
{
   "_id":"02a33b9a-284c-4869-885e-d46981fdd679",
   "context":{
      "products":[
         {
         "id": "e68fc86a-b4ad-4588-b182-ae9ee3db25e4",
         "version": "2020-03-14T13:18:41.296+00:00"
         }
      ],
   },
}
```

Product document:

```
{
   "_id":"e68fc86a-b4ad-4588-b182-ae9ee3db25e4",
   "context":{
      "name": "My Product",
      "image": "someimage"
   },
}
```

So I'm trying to do a lookup for a products in order document, but the result should contain combined fields, like so:

```
"products":[
             {
             "_id": "e68fc86a-b4ad-4588-b182-ae9ee3db25e4",
             "version": "2020-03-14T13:18:41.296+00:00",
             "name": "My Product",
             "image": "someimage"
             }
          ],
```

Not sure how to do this, should I do it outside of the lookup, or inside? This is my aggregation

```
Orders.aggregate([
{
   "$lookup":{
      "from":"products",
      "let":{
         "products":"$context.products"
      },
      "pipeline":[
         {
            "$match":{
               "$expr":{
                  "$in":[
                     "$_id",
                     "$$products.id"
                  ]
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "$project":{
               "_id":0,
               "id":1,
               "name":"$context.name"
            }
         }
      ],
      "as":"mergedProducts"
   }
},
{
   "$project":{
      "context":"$context",
      "mergedProducts":"$mergedProducts"
   }
},
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run that mapping outside of `$lookup` by running [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) along with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get single pair from both arrays and then apply [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) to get one object as a result:

```
db.Order.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "products",
            localField: "context.products.id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "productDetails"
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            productDetails: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$productDetails",
                    in: {
                        _id: "$$this._id",
                        name: "$$this.context.name"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            "context.products": {
                $map: {
                    input: "$context.products",
                    as: "prod",
                    in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$prod",
                            { $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$productDetails", cond: { $eq: [ "$$this._id", "$$prod.id" ] } } }, 0 ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/elEjF6kogiR)

The goals of the last step is to take take two arrays: `products` and `productDetails` (the output of `$lookup`) and find matches between them. We know there's always one match so we can get only one item `$arrayElemAt 0`. As an output of `$map` there will be single array containing "merged" documents.

Comment: Thank you very much, kind sir.

Comment: Nice.   Deserves some comments in that last stage.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti thanks, please review if it's more clear now